# How to exclude subdirectory in Jekyll config

Tags: html, directory, jekyll, static-generator

I know that this is a major problem, and there is a million topics about this but nowhere i can't find how to exclude an subfolder from jekyll structure. I've tried all possible configurations and even one of them is not working :(

```
exclude: font/fontcustom
exclude: [font/fontcustom]
exclude: ['font/fontcustom']
exclude: /font/fontcustom
exclude: font/.../
exclude: font/*
```

etc. Can anybody help? Please don't suggest to add this to `.gitignore` file bc this is not a solution of this problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it on my machine, and this works for me:

```
exclude: [font/fontcustom]
```

I'm on Windows 8 with [Portable Jekyll 3.1.1](https://github.com/madhur/PortableJekyll), if that matters.